# Cast error when using $gt ,$gte, $lt ,$lte in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this

```
{
    "_id":"5dfa6e23ef4b260e8c23a70c",
    "username":"foo",
    "count":4,
    "log":[
            {"description":"Eat sandwich","duration":30,"date":1576454400000,"_id":"5dfa6e49ef4b260e8c23a70e"},
            {"description":"Eat sandwich","duration":300,"date":1576458700000,"_id":"5dfa6f1c2924c010b35c6b60"},
            {"description":"Eat sandwich","duration":400,"date":1576459000000,"_id":"5dfa6f3a2924c010b35c6b61"},
            {"description":"Eat sandwich","duration":400,"date":1576457400000,"_id":"5dfa6f702924c010b35c6b62"}

          ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the activities of a user's activities from a date  range like this.

```
Activities.findOne({username:"foo",log:{date:{$gt: 1576454400000, $lt: 1576458700000 }}},function(err,activities){
//Do something
});
```

I always get a cast error whether the type is date or number. I have tried almost everything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `log:date` should be changed to `log.date`

Comment: @Subburaj  I'm sorrry I made a typo. please check that section again. I've corrected it.

Comment: I ran your query from _mongo shell_ and have no _cast error_. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the given input document in the post, the following query matches and returns the document (NOTE: in *mongo shell*).

This query uses `$elemMatch`:

```
db.test.findOne( { log: { $elemMatch: { date: { $gt: 1576454400000, $lte: 1576458700000 } } } } )
```

In case you do not use `$elemMatch`, the document field in the array *must* be specified using the dot (`.`) notation; e.g., `"log.date"`.

```
db.test.findOne( { "log.date": { $gt: 1576454400000, $lte: 1576458700000 } } )
```

The query you are using will not give any syntax errors, but return wrong results.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't get the cast error anymore when I used $elemMatch. Now I'm getting an empty object no matter the date range.

Comment: Is there any data in the collection? Can you check from the _mongo shell_ or Compass, etc.

Comment: Yes there's data and now all the data is returned no matter the range. The project is on glitch. I don't know if glitch has something to do with it.